# Where can I ask questions about musical pieces? Not playing them

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to figure out a place to ask a question not about playing a musical piece, but about the contents of that piece.

Specifically, I want to know who exclaims "salt peanuts" in Dizzy Gillespie/Charlie Parker's "Salt Peanuts."

This is not the correct stackexchange site for such a thing, is there a stackexchange for such questions?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Dizzy. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6N8eL-cuEU

Comment: Thanks.  That is a crazy song.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no site where that would be on-topic. However, [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=z_YAYy-nPlhlGleSE5XxcQ2) is a site that has been proposed where your question would be on-topic.